# Review / moderation system incorrect censuring

Tags: discussion, bug

I was doing my bit, reviewing questions and answers. I was presented with a ridiculous answer on [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/641520/drbd-can-not-start-the-can-not-load-the-drbd-module) that [Sven](https://serverfault.com/users/8897/sven) had already deleted.

Because the answer had already been deleted I hit "no action needed". Of course the system did it's rather insulting "stop look and listen (you imbecile)" response, I assume because that would typically allow the answer to stand.

The answer was already deleted, why would I select anything else? This seems like a bug, or at least a situation that the reviewing system doesn't handle well. When I review I don't just look at the answer presented to me, I often open the question and look at it in context.

The systems "be more careful with your reviewing" response comes across as rather insulting, to the point that it puts me off reviewing.

Comment: Yup, the review system and especially that very common error situation sucks big time. Sorry, but the [SE] staff appears to disagree and left that system essentially unchanged for years now. I stopped reviewing because of this...

Comment: I'm fairly sure I haven't been in the review queue for 12+ months because of this crap. Perhaps since I was elected as a mod.

Comment: The audit was trying to make it look like the answer had not yet been deleted and was expecting you to downvote or flag.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. I just don't think it's a particularly good way to do things.